# Setting PHP Variable if condition

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm creating a function that has to check for several inputs and create a variable that I use to call a SQL query, the problem I'm facing is that I want to change a variable so that I don't use the SELECT call every time, but instead the AND call. How does one construct such a function? This is what I currently have.

```
if ($_GET['filtering2'] != "" || $_GET['filtering3'] != "" || $_GET['filtering4'] != "" || $_GET['filtering5'] != "" || $_GET['filtering6'] != "" || $_GET['filtering7'] != "" || $_GET['filtering7'] != "") {

    function searchByColumn($values, $columnName)
    {
        $string = implode(" OR season LIKE ", $values);
        if ($firstTime = 2) {

            return "SELECT * FROM shrubs2 WHERE season LIKE $string";

        } else {
            return " AND WHERE season LIKE $string";
        }
    }

    $colNames = array("season"); // can add here more column names
    foreach ($colNames as $colName) {
        $str .= searchByColumn($array_name, $colName);
        $firstTime = 3;
    }
}
if ($_GET['filtering8'] != "" || $_GET['filtering9'] != "" || $_GET['filtering10'] != "" || $_GET['filtering11'] != "") {

    function searchByColumn2($values, $columnName2)
    {
        $string2 = implode(" OR 日照 LIKE ", $values);
        if ($firstTime = 2) {
            return "SELECT * FROM shrubs2 WHERE 日照 LIKE $string2";

        } else {
            return " AND WHERE 日照 LIKE $string2";
        }
    }

    $colNames2 = array("日照"); // can add here more column names
    foreach ($colNames2 as $colName2) {
        $str .= searchByColumn2($array_name2, $colName2);
        $firstTime = 3;
    }

}
```

I was trying to change the variable $firstTime, but it never resulted as I wished for it to do.

first edit:

```
if($_GET['filtering8'] != "" || $_GET['filtering9'] != "" || $_GET['filtering10'] != "" || $_GET['filtering11'] != "" ){

function searchByColumn2($values, $columnName2) {
  $string2 = implode(" OR 日照 LIKE ", $values);
  if($firstTime != 3){
  return "SELECT * FROM shrubs2 WHERE 日照 LIKE $string2";
  $firstTime = 3;
} else{
  return " AND WHERE 日照 LIKE $string2";
}
}


$colNames2 = array("日照"); // can add here more column names
foreach($colNames2 as $colName2) {
$str .= searchByColumn2($array_name2, $colName2);

}

}
```

and of course I've added:
       global $firstTime;

Comment: Where do you define `$array_name`, `$array_name2` and `$str`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the variable is global you need to define the global by adding

```
global $firstTime;
```

on first line of `searchByColumn` and `searchByColumn2` function. it will refer to global variable `$firstTime`

Comment: so I should define global $firstTime;  and then. set the value like normally?

Comment: I. made a first edit so you can take a look, it doesn't seem to work for some reason

Comment: I mean like this  `function searchByColumn($values, $columnName) { global $firstTime; $string = implode(" OR season LIKE ", $values); if ($firstTime = 2) { return "SELECT * FROM shrubs2 WHERE season LIKE $string"; } else { return " AND WHERE season LIKE $string"; } }`